# Resizing images to cover % of div by surface area

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic app. I have a two column layout of squares, for an example let's say they're 100x100. I'd like to rescale and then center (horizontally and vertically) images within those squares.

The images to put in them, however, do not have identical aspect ratios. I'd like to resize images to cover the same surface area, regardless of dimensions.

Again, for example, let's say that I want each image to cover 25% of my squares in the grid. If I have a 1000x1000 image, it would be resized to 50x50 to cover 25% of the area within a square. If I had a 500x250 image, it would be resized to ~70x35.

Mathematically I understand at least one way how to do this: image dimension * sqrt((image width x image height) / (0.25)(div width x div height)). It's in code with Angular, however, that I'm struggling.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use CSS if possible. It will be much lighter for the browser to render this and much easier for you to implement.

To do this, create boxes in your template and each box will have an image as a background. You can set that using `ng-style` attribute on the box.

In your CSS you could do something like this:

```
.image-box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! I considered an approach like this, but it would lead to square images (20x20) looking significantly larger than a rectangular image (say 10x20).